# How can I get the space avaiable in a Layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, scaling, space

I have a borderLayout with this distribution:
[image]

In the red position I want to put an image scaled so that it fills all the space available. Also I have the option to show the image with different scales of the real image (20%, 50%, 100%...).

I'm trying to find the scale factor that makes the image fit perfectly:

```
    //GET VALUES
    int imageWidth = image1.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image1.getHeight();
    System.out.println("Image: "+imageWidth + " "+ imageHeight);
    int targetWidth = this.getBounds().width;
    int targetHeight = this.getBounds().height;
    System.out.println("Target: " + targetWidth + " "+ targetHeight);

    //GET SCALE
    float scaleWidth=1;
    float scaleHeight=1;
    if (imageWidth > targetWidth) {
        scaleWidth = (float) targetWidth  / (float) imageWidth;
     }
    if (imageHeight > targetHeight) {
        scaleHeight = (float) targetHeight / (float) imageHeight;
     } 

    return min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
```

The problem is that I can't find the size of the available space (For BorderLayout.CENTER). I wrote in the code the window size but that is incorrect, I also tried with:

```
 this.getLayout().preferredLayoutSize(this).width;
```

but it gives also an incorrect value or at least not what I'm trying to find. And I can't find any other method related to the size. And trying to get the value from the panel which is going to be there is not feasible as I need the value before creating it.

Could anyone tell me how could I find this value?
Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to specify the framework you are using. Seems like you are using AWT/swing?

Comment: @PEMapModder yes, sorry, I've just added it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be attempting to get the size available.

If you really want to know this value then you should do custom painting and dynamically resize the image and paint the image in the `paintComponent()` method.

So the basic code would be something like:

```
public class ImagePanel extend JPanel
{
    public ImagePane(...)
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        // do your scaling

        g.drawImage(...);
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to do dynamic scaling then you can add a `ComponentListener` to your panel and handle the `componentResized` event. Then you can get the real size of the panel and do your scaling calculations. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Component Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Finally you can also use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will automatically scale an Icon based on the space available. All you need to do is create a `JLabel` using the `StretchIcon` and add it to your GUI.